# Mysql crashes on every reboot

Tags: mysql, innodb, vps

I have VPS (Ubuntu 14.04) on digitalocean (1G RAM) and i installed VestaCP. Every time i reboot the server mysql crushes because of lack of memory (it buffers more than 1G) inspite i configured for my RAM (my /etc/mysql/my.cnf):

```
    [client]
port=3306
socket=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock

[mysqld_safe]
socket=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock

[mysqld]
user=mysql
pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
socket=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
port=3306
basedir=/usr
datadir=/var/lib/mysql
tmpdir=/tmp
lc-messages-dir=/usr/share/mysql
log_error=/var/log/mysql/error.log
max_user_connections=30
wait_timeout=30
interactive_timeout=50
long_query_time=5
innodb_file_per_table

#fibhost 1G RAM
key_buffer_size                 = 8M
query_cache_size                = 0M
tmp_table_size                  = 64M
innodb_buffer_pool_size         = 128M
innodb_additional_mem_pool_size = 8M
innodb_log_buffer_size          = 8M
max_connections                 = 150

sort_buffer_size                = 4M
read_buffer_size                = 128k
read_rnd_buffer_size            = 256k
join_buffer_size                = 128M
thread_stack                    = 256k
binlog_cache_size               = 32k

!includedir /etc/mysql/conf.d/
```

When I `sudo service mysql` restart it works propely and buffers 550M until next reboot `shutdown -r +5` or `reboot`

/var/log/mysql/error.log:

```
150529  0:36:43 InnoDB: Could not open or create data files.
150529  0:36:43 InnoDB: If you tried to add new data files, and it failed here,
150529  0:36:43 InnoDB: you should now edit innodb_data_file_path in my.cnf back
150529  0:36:43 InnoDB: to what it was, and remove the new ibdata files InnoDB created
150529  0:36:43 InnoDB: in this failed attempt. InnoDB only wrote those files full of
150529  0:36:43 InnoDB: zeros, but did not yet use them in any way. But be careful: do not
150529  0:36:43 InnoDB: remove old data files which contain your precious data!
150529  0:36:43 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned error.
150529  0:36:43 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
150529  0:36:43 [ERROR] Unknown/unsupported storage engine: InnoDB
150529  0:36:43 [ERROR] Aborting

150529  0:36:43 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete

150529 00:36:43 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid ended
```

Comment: FYI, the word you want is "crash," not "crush."

Comment: how do you have mysql configured to run when you reboot the machine? is it as root?

Comment: and how to configure to start mysql from root?

Comment: also i have this problem in my vestacp panel , maybe its from vesta, i have other server not contain vestacp and the mysql is great

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1GB is pitifully tiny for today.  Cut in half the 64M and 128M settings in my.cnf; maybe that will keep you from running out of RAM.

The log file sounds like there is a permission problem with the directory where MySQL wants to put its stuff, or with the files that are there.  Do not run mysqld directly from a non-root user; the service command is probably the "right" way.